# Haskell Stack can't find PATH because of conda is installed also

Tags: path, conda, haskell-stack

I'm learning Haskell Stack in college. I've hit a problem with my $PATH. From what I can tell is because I also have conda installed. What I'm doing, I've installed Haskell Stack fine and follow the directions to set up project:

```
stack new MyFirstProject
cd MyFirstProject
stack build  
stack install
```

All fine until `stack install` I get the error:

```
Copying from /Users/jamesmurphy/modules/Functional_Programming/Week5/MyFirstProject/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/cc05e4baf51e8b4a394e9151b943fe70c815c04c30f6eb1688f4a9e027d758ca/8.10.7/bin/MyFirstProject-exe to /Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin/MyFirstProject-exe

Copied executables to /Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin:
- MyFirstProject-exe

Warning: Installation path /Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin
         not found on the PATH environment variable.
```

I checked the $PATH to see what it was set to using `nano .bash_profile` and its set as

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/jamesmurphy/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hoo$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/jamesmurphy/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/jamesmurphy/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/jamesmurphy/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I'm a bit lost with this as I've never seen $PATH like this before.

So I have tried adding to this $PATH by using `nano .bash_profile` and added this to the top.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Still wont work, So I Just replaced all the conda stuff with

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

I need to add this PATH but don't know the right way to do it with the conda stuff also. I've messed around with a few times trying a couple of different things and cant figure it out. I opened a new terminal every time I made a change. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated. Thank you

Updated

Sorry I might have left info out. The 'stack install' is suppose to make an executable file of the program. Haskel Stack is in installed correctly already. If I run

```
/Users/jamesmurphy/modules/Functional_Programming/Week5/MyFirstProject/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/cc05e4baf51e8b4a394e9151b943fe70c815c04c30f6eb1688f4a9e027d758ca/8.10.7/bin/MyFirstProject-exe
```

it will run the program. I'm being told to add `/Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin` to my $PATH but when I do this it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haskell, but if your Haskell stuff just needs to have some binaries in `$PATH`, Anaconda stuff also being in `$PATH` is not a conflict - it's convention to _append_ to `$PATH` and often a lot of junk gets thrown in there. You should follow whatever install instructions are provided with Haskell and act like Anaconda is not installed.

Comment: Sorry I really bad at explaining this as I'm still just learning, I followed the install instructions and it has installed correctly. The 'stack install' command is suppose to make an executable file to run the program and that’s s where the $PATH error comes from. If I run '/Users/jamesmurphy/modules/Functional_Programming/Week5/MyFirstProject/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/cc05e4baf51e8b4a394e9151b943fe70c815c04c30f6eb1688f4a9e027d758ca/8.10.7/bin/MyFirstProject-exe to /Users/jamesmurphy/.local/bin/MyFirstProject-exe' the program runs. Not getting much help in college fixing the issue.